# Pass type from variable

Tags: kotlin

I want to use method from the external library to load my assets files, declaration of that function:

```
inline fun <reified T> loadSync(path: String): T = loadSync(getAssetDescriptor(path))
```

And I would like to have enum to store all my assets paths and types, currently, it looks like that:

```
enum class Asset (val path: String, val clazz: Class<*>){
    // Textures
    LOADER("splash-screen/loader.png", Texture::class.java),
    // ...
}
```

and it will be great if it will be possible to make something like that

```
assetStorage.loadSync<Asset.LOADER.clazz>(Asset.LOADER.path)
```

but I don't know how to correct declare `clazz`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an expression like `Asset.LOADER.clazz` for a Generic type argument. You would either have to provide the type as

```
assetStorage.loadSync<Texture>(Asset.LOADER.path)
```

or have to create a wrapping function around the `loadSync` function passing the class as an argument, so that the compiler can infer the type as below

```
@Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER")
inline fun <reified T> newLoadSync(path: String, clazz: T): String = loadSync<T>(path)
```

and use it as

```
assetStorage.newLoadSync(Asset.LOADER.path, Asset.LOADER.clazz)
```

Comment: Even when I implement Your solution it's not working as expected. probably I have to do some variable transformation. I got the exception: `No loader available for assets of type: class java.lang.Class`

Comment: Where is that exception coming from @Alcadur?

Comment: From the library, I found the place where it's run `T::class.java`. So I have to find a way to store `Texture` class in which after call `myVar::class.java` will be equal `Texture::class.java`

Comment: I prepared some sample code so You can check any ideas ;) `https://pl.kotl.in/ky1opNFn3`